# R Programming - Identify items with exceptional sequence

Tags: r, analysis

I have data in format similar to this:

```
ID  Timestamp   Status
1   1/1/2014    1
2   1/1/2014    1
3   1/2/2014    1
4   1/3/2014    1
1   1/3/2014    2
3   1/3/2014    2
4   1/5/2014    2
5   1/5/2014    1
1   1/6/2014    3
2   1/7/2014    3
3   1/8/2014    3
4   1/9/2014    3
5   1/10/2014   2
6   1/10/2014   1
3   1/10/2014   4
3   1/10/2014   5
3   1/10/2014   6
1   1/11/2014   4
2   1/11/2014   3
3   1/11/2014   4
3   1/11/2014   2
5   1/11/2014   3
6   1/12/2014   4
7   1/12/2014   5
5   1/12/2014   6
4   1/12/2014   7
2   1/13/2014   3
3   1/13/2014   4
1   1/14/2014   5
5   1/14/2014   3
6   1/14/2014   4
1   1/15/2014   6
1   1/16/2014   7
```

Each ID have to go through status from 1 to 7 in order `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7`

However, due to the data entry error, sometime the 4 happen before 3, 6 happen before 2, 7 happen before 1.

So can R help to identify the IDs that have status change not as the rule?

For above sample data - Only ID **1** have the correct status history `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7` - Others are note correct.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can they skip levels? Can they repeat levels? Are there any valid IDs in your example? Or better yet, give the expected output for your sample input.

Comment: Edited the question, adding some more line and the expected output that only one ID **1** have correct status change. Thanks Flick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's OK for ID's to skip and duplicate statuses (just never go backwards) You could do something like this. Here's the data.frame I used to test

```
dd<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L), Timestamp = structure(c(18262, 18262, 
18263, 18264, 18264, 18264, 18266, 18266, 18267, 18268, 18269, 
18270, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18271, 18272, 18272, 18272, 
18272, 18272, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18273, 18274, 18274, 18275, 
18275, 18275, 18276, 18277), class = "Date"), Status = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L
)), .Names = c("ID", "Timestamp", "Status"), row.names = c(NA, 
-33L), class = "data.frame")
```

And then I define a helper function to test that all the difference in the status values are are all 1 and that we have all seven of them

```
isgoodseq<-function(x) {
    length(x) ==7 & all(diff(x)==1) & min(x)==1
}
```

Now we run this for each ID (making sure the data is in the correct order)

```
with(dd[order(dd$Timestamp, dd$ID, dd$Status),], 
    tapply(Status, ID, isgoodseq))
```

And that gives us

```
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Which means 1 is the only good ID

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your updated data and definitions

Comment: Thank you very much for a very detail answer! I have much more complicated tasks but your answer has give me ideas to start with as I am new to R and practicing using R. - again - Thank you!